# How to select columns from two tables sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to select three columns from two different tables in sql server 2008. i tried below query but its show error like this

error message

```
Column 'tb_new_product_Name_id.Product_Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

query

```
select pn.Product_Name as [Product Name], pn.Product_Id as [Product Id],COUNT(pnd.Product_id)+1 as duplicate_id 
from tb_new_product_Name_id as pn,tb_new_product_Name_id_duplicate as pnd 
where  pn.Product_Name LIKE '%'+@product_name_id+'%' 
or (pn.Product_Id like '%'+@product_name_id+'%' and pnd.Product_Id like '%'+@product_name_id+'%' );
```

where i made mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to have a `count` in your select statement you have to group on the other columns

```
select pn.Product_Name as [Product Name], pn.Product_Id as [Product Id],COUNT(pnd.Product_id)+1 as duplicate_id 
from tb_new_product_Name_id as pn
  ,tb_new_product_Name_id_duplicate as pnd 
where  pn.Product_Name LIKE '%'+@product_name_id+'%' 
  or (pn.Product_Id like '%'+@product_name_id+'%' and pnd.Product_Id like '%'+@product_name_id+'%' );
group by pn.Product_name, pn.Product_ID
```

You should also look at using [explicit join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins) syntax

Answer (score 1):

You're using [aggregate function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) COUNT, so you need to group by the other column that are not part in the aggregate.

Try this:

```
select pn.Product_Name as [Product Name], pn.Product_Id as [Product Id],COUNT(pnd.Product_id)+1 as duplicate_id from tb_new_product_Name_id as pn,tb_new_product_Name_id_duplicate as pnd 
where  pn.Product_Name LIKE '%'+@product_name_id+'%' or (pn.Product_Id like '%'+@product_name_id+'%' and pnd.Product_Id like '%'+@product_name_id+'%' )
group by pn.Product_Name, pn.Product_Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **GROUPBY** when you are selecting any columns with Aggregate functions like count.

**Try the following query:**

```
  select pn.Product_Name as [Product Name], pn.Product_Id as [Product Id],COUNT(pnd.Product_id)+1 as duplicate_id from tb_new_product_Name_id as pn,tb_new_product_Name_id_duplicate as pnd where  pn.Product_Name LIKE '%'+@product_name_id+'%' or (pn.Product_Id like '%'+@product_name_id+'%' and pnd.Product_Id like '%'+@product_name_id+'%' ) Group by pn.productname,pn.ProductID
```

Hope it helps..